# Generate sampling

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to run a stratified random sampling using the below script (also access it here -  https://code.earthengine.google.com/d86104c83646470cbddcc0387a89f690).

But, I need to estabilish the minimum distance condition (for example, 100 meters) between the samples.

So I would like to know if is there a way to do that?

```js
var LULUCF = ee.Image(
    "users/herciloodorico/zambezia_RF_pb_lulucf17"),
    study_area = 
        /* color: #d63000 */
        /* displayProperties: [
          { "type": "rectangle"}
        ] */
        ee.Geometry.Polygon(
            [[[34.922070312499955, -14.939797912211477],
            [34.922070312499955, -18.9949224637123],
            [39.250683593749955, -18.9949224637123],
            [39.250683593749955, -14.939797912211477]]], 
            null, 
            false
        );

// Display classified map
var palette = [
    '#ffffff', // no data (0) // white
    '#ce0000', // high probability (1) // red
    '#ffa500', // buffer (2)           // orange
    '#ffff00', // low probability  (3) // yellow
    '#367d49', // forest (4) // green
    '#bfc4bf', // nonforest (5) // gray
];

Map.addLayer(LULUCF, {min: 0, max: 5, palette: palette}, 'LULUCF');

print(LULUCF);

////////////////////////////////////////
// Creating a stratified random sample//
////////////////////////////////////////

// Add lat lon
var inputs = LULUCF.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat());

print(inputs);

var points = inputs.stratifiedSample({
    numPoints: 3000, 
    classBand: "classification", 
    region: study_area, 
    scale: 20,
    classValues: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    classPoints: [0, 125, 125, 125, 100, 100],
});

var palette = ee.List([
    '#ffffff', 
    '#ce0000', 
    '#ffa500', 
    '#ffff00', 
    '#367d49', 
    '#4da5bd'
]);
var values = ee.List([0,1,2,3,4,5]);

var reference_points = points.map(function(f) {
    var klass = f.get("classification")
    return ee.Feature(
        ee.Geometry.Point([
            f.get('longitude'), 
            f.get('latitude')
        ]), 
        f.toDictionary()
    ).set({style: {color: palette.get(klass) }})
});

// Display the sampling
Map.addLayer(
    reference_points.style({styleProperty: "style"}),
    {}, 
    "Reference Points", 
    true
);
Map.centerObject(reference_points,8);
```

Answer (score 1):

My initial guess would be to define a scale of 100m:

```
var points100 = inputs.stratifiedSample({
  numPoints: 3000, 
  classBand: "classification", 
  region: study_area, 
  scale: 100,
  classValues: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  classPoints: [0, 125, 125, 125, 100, 100],
});
```

But I haven't actually tested if that works?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work out.